# How to edit Devise edit user path to fall under the username?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

When using the Devise gem, by default the user edit path falls under /signup/edit or /registration/edit. How can we change this to /username/edit? I have already updated the user profile url using FriendlyID to use the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the edit devise paths as follows, Devise provides to override its current path names.

```
devise_for :users do
   get ':user/edit-profile' => 'devise/registration#edit', :as => :edit_user_profile
end
```

your link will be like

```
edit_user_profile_path(current_user)
```